# OWIN Middleware and Dependency Injection Per Request with Unity in Asp.NET WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, owin, unity-container

I'm trying to build some OWIN middleware that is resolved by Unity on a per request basis in Asp.NET WebApi. (Not DotNetCore!)

**Problem #1:**
I can't figure out how to pass `next` to the constructor of the `OwinMiddleware` implementation. This code won't compile as `next` is `Func<Task>` and the constructor expects type `OwinMiddleware`.

```
public class CustomMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public CustomMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var middleware = new CustomMiddleware(next);
    await middleware.Invoke(context);
});
```

I've managed to get around this by not implementing `OwinMiddleware`, however this feels wrong. Surely there's a way to make this work correctly?

**Problem #2:**
As mentioned before, I've sidestepped the `OwinMiddleware` implementation issue. Now I want to inject an object into `CustomMiddleware` and that **same** object scoped **per request** must be resolved by an `TestController` further down the request pipeline, however I'm seeing different instances of the object resolved in the  `CustomMiddleware` and `TestController` for the same request.

```
public class InjectedObject
{
    public string Instance = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}

public class CustomMiddleware
{
    private readonly InjectedObject _obj;

    public CustomMiddleware(InjectedObject obj)
    {
        _obj = obj;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context, Func<Task> next)
    {
        //Do stuff with my object
        await next();
    }
}
```

And within the app configuration method:

```
container.RegisterType<CustomMiddleware>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<InjectedObject>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var middleware = container.Resolve<CustomMiddleware>();
    await middleware.Invoke(context, next);
});
```

And when the controller is called the InjectedObject is different to the one that was injected into CustomMiddleware.

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    private readonly InjectedObject _obj;

    public TestController(InjectedObject obj)
    {
        _obj = obj;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem #2: Do you try to change to this lifetime manager: ContainerControlledLifetimeManager?

Comment: Problem #1: Please refer to this http://benfoster.io/blog/how-to-write-owin-middleware-in-5-different-steps, if it helps.

Comment: @Phuc Thai yes I tried the ContainerControllerLifetimeManager - this returns the instance as expected as the scope of the object is now singleton and not per request. As for the blog post, I did read it and it unfortunately offers no help in this matter.

Comment: have you found solution for your problem ? I'm facing the same issue.